# iFrame redirect issue

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a redirect problem with iframe. I explain:

My iframe is located within the domain www.example.com/forum/ and points to the mainpage of www.example2.com/forum/

the iframe works well and allows me to visit all the pages that are contained in www.example2.com/forum/

The problem comes when I try to login. After the popup, where I enter the username and password, the database recognizes me but the redirect directs me to the start page of the iframe www.example2.com/forum/ without being logged.

In short words:

**I can not log in even though the db recognizes me, but I can navigate easily on any page I want.**

My iFrame:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.example2.com/forum/" />
```

What can it be?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you visit the page at www.example2.com/forum in the browser (not in an iframe)?

Comment: No out of the iframe everything works perfectly and I have no problems with redirects

Comment: is your second website under https?

Comment: maybe you should set X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example1.com/ in your http response header.

Comment: We need a lot more information if we're going to be able to help you.  What is the authentication?  What is the point of the iframe?  What server-side language are you using?  Why have you tagged the question `Javascript` but have no code?  You've literally given us nothing more than "it doesn't work".  Please read **[ask]** and update the question accordingly.

Comment: it's http no hhtps. anyway, yes, it's like a separate site inside a subfolder of my site